# How to all the test runs form ALM using ALM REST API?

Tags: java, rest, api, alm, hp-alm

I am trying to fetch all the test runs from HP ALM using the ALM REST API, but my results are limited to only 100 records. I tried using the query as "?page-size =5000", but that doesn't work.

I am using the below link to fetch the test runs:
"rest/domains/"+domain+"/projects/"+project+"/run"

Please can anyone help me out here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: usually rest apis come with a documentation. have you looked for one?

Answer (score 0):

There are global limitation on the number of records which are returned for a REST call.
It is controlled by `REST_API_DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE` and `REST_API_MAX_PAGE_SIZE` parameters.
See: [this](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/alm/en/12.55/api_refs/REST_TECH_PREVIEW/ALM_REST_API_TP.html#REST_API_Tech_Preview/General/Data_Paging.html%3FTocPath%3DHow%2520to%2520Do%2520Common%2520Tasks%7CQuery%2520a%2520Collection%2520of%2520Entities%7C_____5) and [this](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/alm/en/12.60/api_refs/site_params/metadata.htm) for further details

Comment: Yes but do you know how to set this parameter in the code? I tried setting it up in the api link for runs but it didn't work.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not aware of REST API for Site Administration. Official documentation shows only COM-based API for it: https://admhelp.microfocus.com/alm/en/12.60/api_refs/site_admin/Default.htm

Answer (score 0):

*(You don't mention the ALM version you're using. The following applies to v12.55:)*

---

It seems you're using the wrong parameter `page-size="5000"`. Instead, try `limit="5000"`

> **Specifying the Page Size in the Query**
>
> The client can indicate the number of instances to return in each page using the query parameter `limit="n"`. For example:
>
> `/qcbin/api/domains/{domain}/projects/{project}/tests?limit=20`

As already mentioned, keep in mind the site paramaters `REST_API_PAGINATION_MAX_LIMIT` (maximum page size, default 2000) and `REST_API_PAGINATION_DEFAULT_LIMIT` (default page size, default is 100).

Further reading: https://admhelp.microfocus.com/alm/en/12.55/api_refs/REST/Default.htm#REST_API/Data_Paging.htm